# How to configure nginx ingress rules without "host"

Tags: kubernetes, https, devops, nginx-ingress, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have installed nginx ingress in kubernetes from official documenation. But while configuring the rules without mentioning the "host". I am getting the below erros.

error
++++++
spec.rules[0].host: Required value

Is it possible to configure it without host as I want to access it using only IP address

and I also found the below deployment file with which I am able to apply rules without "host". But not sure is this is safe to use. Please guide me here

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.44.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml

Comment: Have you tried setting the value of `host:` to the ip address?

Comment: I did. It's not working as it needs only DNS name

Comment: Please provide your ingress and yaml files.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to configure the ingress? The ingress controller is different from ingress itself. If you are configuring ingress, then host is completely optional. If host is omitted, all the http traffic is directed through IP address by default. Refer to this documentation for more info https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/